# What is the origin of the Yiddish word "nebach"? Is there a Jewish, Biblical source?

Tags: words, etymology, yiddish

I've found numerous articles about what the word "nebach" (נעבעך) means, for example here and here.

However, I have not been able to determine the true source of it.

Is this word, so commonly used in Jewish lingo, based in Tanach or have some distinctly Jewish roots (like for example the word "maven") or is it simply an adopted word from another language?

Comment: My conjecture - See Shmot (Ex.) 14:3 which uses the term נְבוּכִים . See Rashbam's and Ha'emek Davar's commentary (via Sefaria, e.g.) which imply the terms "confused" and "lost". In Yiddish, the term means something like "a sorry, unfortunate person", which is related, in a way, to a person who has lost a sense of direction towards a successful path.

Comment: Please link the two "here"s in your question body.

Comment: While OP does ask about a Biblical source, is this still a "language- only question?

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26672105#26672105 et seqq.

Comment: @DanF I have heard Rav Matis Weinberg make that assertion of connecting it to נבוכים.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%9A

Answer (score 4):

According to vocabulary.com, it is a Yiddish word of Slavic origin akin to "nebohy," Czech for "wretched;" & "niebożę", Polish for "poor creature" (see also nieborak).